# IF INDEX MATCH multiple criteria between value return "x"

Tags: arrays, indexing, excel-formula, match

```
A         B        C          D        E
Id      Status  gmtDate      Gmt   Length
A       online  01.02.15    07:03   00:03
A       offline 01.02.15    07:06   29:02
A       online  02.02.15    12:08   00:39
A       pause   02.02.15    12:47   00:46
A       online  02.02.15    13:34   00:24
A       online  02.02.15    13:58   00:00
A       offline 02.02.15    13:59   00:11
A       online  02.02.15    14:11   03:52
A       offline 02.02.15    18:03   21:03
A       online  03.02.15    15:06   01:41
A       pause   03.02.15    16:48   02:12
A       offline 03.02.15    19:00   17:57
```

This is sheet one. It is basically an availability table. From when to when an agent was online, offline or on pause. The available info is date, time and duration between different statuses.

I used:

```
=E4-E3+(E3>E4)
```

to calculate the duration.

I then used an array formula with Multiple Criteria to find Gmt time.

```
I3=01.02.15
J3=online
```

As my references to test.

```
=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(I3&J3,$C:$C&$B:$B,0))
```

Which gives "07:03"

And I know that from online it can either transition to offline or pause I can use the cell directly below to stop the online time. I there fore used this:

```
=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(I3&J3,$C:$C&$B:$B,0)+1)
```

Which gives "07:06"

I want to enter value into cells based on a combination of those array formulas.

```
      A           B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       
    Online     Offine   Pause
     Date      Hours  Minutes  07:00   07:01   07:02   07:03   07:04   07:05   
    01.02.15    0,0      3       OFF     OFF      OFF     ON      ON     ON
    02.02.15    0,0      0                                              
    03.02.15    0,0      0                                              
    04.02.15    0,0      0
```

The table above is what I am aiming for. With only the instance for 01.02.15 shown.

I want to basically stop referring to I3 and J3 and start inputting into a time tracking sheet.

This is for me to track when agents are online offline or pause. Starting from D2 the time stretches 24 hours by minute. I want to fill in D2 with either ON=online, OFF=offline and P=pause.

All formulas below entered on MAC using Cmd+Return

Online:

```
=IF(AND(D2>=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(A3&A1,$C:$C&$B:$B,0)),D2<INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(A3&A1,$D:$D&$C:$C,0)+1))),"ON","")
```

Offline:

```
=IF(AND(D2>=(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(A3&B1,$C:$C&$B:$B,0)),D2<(INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(A3&B1,$D:$D&$C:$C,0)+1)))),"OFF","")
```

Pause:

```
=IF(AND(D2>=(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(A3&C1,$C:$C&$B:$B,0)),D2<(INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(A3&C1,$D:$D&$C:$C,0)+1)))),"P","")
```

These formulas work on their own. The problem is that I can have an agent going to the various states (online,offline and pause) multiple times on the same day. I was hoping to use conditional formatting and add the three Rules to the applied cells and then if the instance matched all the criteria have the cells filled in accordingly (ON,OFF,P) but at the same time not just using the first instance where it found matching criteria but every time the conditions are fulfilled.

I tried to do this out of desperation:

And it will find the first instance of online on each date but will not check the entire date column. And the formula is heavy. Take my computer (16gb ram) a long time to calc.

```
=IF(AND(D2>=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(A3&A1,$C:$C&$B:$B,0)),D2<INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(A3&A1,$D:$D&$C:$C,0)+1))),"ON",IF(AND(D2>=(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(A3&B1,$C:$C&$B:$B,0)),D2<(INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(A3&B1,$D:$D&$C:$C,0)+1)))),"OFF",IF(AND(D2>=(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(A3&C1,$C:$C&$B:$B,0)),D2<(INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(A3&C1,$D:$D&$C:$C,0)+1)))),"P","ERR"))
```

And it did not work.

There are multiple match instances because:

```
    A       online  02.02.15    12:08   00:39
    A       pause   02.02.15    12:47   00:46
    A       online  02.02.15    13:34   00:24
    A       online  02.02.15    13:58   00:00
    A       offline 02.02.15    13:59   00:11
    A       online  02.02.15    14:11   03:52
    A       offline 02.02.15    18:03   21:03
```

On the same day the agent is in each state multiple times.

In all honesty I do not need the part for offline. If I could get two conditions. Once to fill in ON and once to fill in P that would be sufficient.

To add some context. This is a time tracking file for agents of an online chat service. This will be used to monitor the agents online. e.g they have an 8 hour shift (480 minutes) they are allowed to be on pause for 1 hour (60 minutes) lunch but still need to have 420 minutes online. The reason I need to do this by minute is because the time tracking will be used to calculate and forecast many different metric such as chat density i.e how many chats do they have over the period how many at the same time etc.

Comment: your cell references are not correct, for example, in your first formula you are indexing E:E but you say you are pulling from D:D when you say 07:03. and same for others. please review them.

Comment: Yes I am going to go through everything again now and add to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: @AHC Thanks for your help the first time I didn't think to change the formulas to english. I have reworked and and checked it several times now. Do you have any insight?